# Git changelog grouped by day and user

Tags: logs, git

Current code to generate change logs:

```
svn2cl --linelen 78 --reparagraph --include-rev --group-by-day
```

The closest I could get with vanilla options is

```
git shortlog --format='* [%h] %s' -w78,8,10
```

How do I emulate the `svn2cl` output as closely as possible?

Example output:

```
2013-02-19  username

        * [r30695] path1: commit message
        * [r30691] path2, path3, path4: looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
          commit message
        * [r30690] path1, path3: commit message

2013-02-19  other_user
        * ...

2013-02-18  username
        * ...
```

**Two issues remain:**

- Include a human-readable list of paths before the commit message
- Pretty-print long commit messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979587/96588) gave the right direction. The result so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read -r -u 9 date name
do
    echo "$date  $name"
    echo
    GIT_PAGER=cat git log --no-merges --committer="$name" --since="$date 00:00:00 +0000" --until="$(date --date="$date + 1 day" +%Y-%m-%d) 00:00:00 +0000" --format='        * [%h] %s'
    echo
done 9< <(git log --no-merges --format=$'%cd %cn' --date=short | sort --unique --reverse)
```

The midnight times were necessary. It looks like for some reason it uses the current time instead of the start of the day by default.

**Two issues remain:**

- Include a human-readable list of paths before the commit message
- Pretty-print long commit messages

Sample output:

```
2013-02-19  username

        * [f97bb5f] commit message
        * [f0e419d] looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong commit message
        * [070e50f] commit message

2013-02-19  other_user
        * ...

2013-02-18  username
        * ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work on OS X, I made some minor modifications to l0b0's solution:

```
git-grouped-log () {
  while read -r -u 9 since name
  do
    until=$(date -j -v+1d -f '%Y-%m-%d' $since +%Y-%m-%d)

    echo "$since $name"
    echo

    GIT_PAGER=cat git log             \
      --no-merges                     \
      --committer="$name"             \
      --since="$since 00:00:00 +0000" \
      --until="$until 00:00:00 +0000" \
      --format='  * [%h] %s'

    echo
  done 9< <(git log --no-merges --format=$'%cd %cn' --date=short | sort --unique --reverse)
}
```

I also wrapped it in a function, because then I can save it in an arbitrary file.

Comment: the git log statement helped me a lot